# Contravariance and operator overload

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have Specification pattern implementation and I wanted to change it to support contravariance. However interesting problem arose.

```
public interface ISpecification<in T>
{
    Func<T, bool> Predicate { get; }
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity);
}

public class Specification<T> : ISpecification<T>
{
    public Specification(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        this.Predicate = predicate;
    }

    public Func<T, bool> Predicate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(T x)
    {
        return Predicate.Invoke(x);
    }

    public static Specification<T> operator &(Specification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
    {
        return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
    }
}
```

this work as you can expect

```
new Specification<DerivedClass>((x) => true) & new Specification<BaseClass> ((x) => true)
```

but if I reverse the order of argument it doesn't compile anymore

```
new Specification<BaseClass>((x) => true) & new Specification<DerivedClass>((x) => true)
```

I understand why this happens but my question is - is there a way to have both working?

EDIT:

I already tried to define operator & with reverse order or params like that

```
public static Specification<T> operator &(ISpecification<T> left, Specification<T> right)
{
    return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
}
```

but I am getting ambiguous call compiler error between both operators. I am using .NET 4.5

netfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GB66UN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes -- just do it again for the other parameter order.

```
public static Specification<T> operator &(ISpecification<T> left, Specification<T> right)
{
    return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
}
```

Operator overloading does not require that the *first* parameter be of the enclosing type, only that *one* of the parameters is.

AS @DStanley points out, even this will fail on a call of the form

```
new Specification<DerivedClass>((x) => true) & new Specification<DerivedClass>((x) => true);
```

So *we do it again*, for this particular combination of parameters:

```
public static Specification<T> operator &(Specification<T> left, Specification<T> right)
{
    return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but I am getting ambiguous call between both operators

Comment: Interesting, that may be a version mismatch. I have this working in LINQPad 5, which targets .NET 4.6 and uses C# 6. I do know the implementation for overload resolution saw changes.

Comment: LINQPad 4 (.NET 4.5) accepts this as well. Can you show the full code that gives the error -- in particular, the call that fails after both overloads are in place?

Comment: It is ambiguous if _both_ arguments use the derived class as the generic parameter.  Adding a _third_ overload solves that :)

Comment: @DStanley: good catch! Updated my answer -- although I fully admit it's getting kind of silly now, and I wonder if there should be something simpler.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong the call is ambiguous when you two specifications of same type here fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GB66UN

Comment: @ekalchev: add the third overload and you'll see this scenario works too. https://dotnetfiddle.net/NwootM

Answer (score 2):

To support both Covariance & Contravariance you need to overload the operator like this

```
public static Specification<T> operator &(ISpecification<T> left, Specification<T> right)
{
    return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
}

public static Specification<T> operator &(Specification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
{
    return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
}

public static Specification<T> operator &(Specification<T> left, Specification<T> right)
{
    return new Specification<T>((x) => left.Predicate(x) && right.Predicate(x));
}
```